# Pass constructor parameters to base constructor implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

Can I avoid having to type out all my base class constructor parameters in my derived class? Ie, see the simple code below:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, .... param10)

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, do I have to retype out all these params again?)
        # also if the base params change I'll need to re-edit this constructor aswell
        # is there an easier way?
```

My class inherits from a base class whose constructor has multiple parameters (~10). So I either need my class constructor to also have these params or maybe python has something where I don't have to physically type them out?

Heres my usecase:

```
class MyModel(peewee.Model):

    ID      = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    name    = peewee.CharField()
    ... many more fields

    def onClick(self, e):
        raise NotImplementedError("method 'MyModel::onClick' should be overridden!")

# MyModel instances can be created as so...
m = MyModel(name='bar', ...) # lots of properties

class FooModel(MyModel):

    # Do I HAVE to explicitly state each parameter? Is there an easier way?
    def __init__(self, ...):
        MyModel.__init__(self, ...)
        # initialise some properties
        self.some_property = 1
        self.another_property = 'foo'

    def onClick(self, e):
        # custom click handling
        ...

# I want to instantiate FooModel's the same way'
m = FooModel(name='bar', ...) # lots of properties
```

Comment: Look into [unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). It's easy.

Comment: `*args, **kwargs`

Comment: @StephenRauch so would my `FooModel` constructor need to be... `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`? Or is self already in `args`... ie should I do `__init(*args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: `self` would be in `args`, but don't do that.

Comment: @StephenRauch dont do what exactly? And what should I do instead?

Comment: *args is all remaining positional args.  So self could be included, but by convention self is generally specified, and the *args would be all of the others.